# New class (and related methods, etc...) wont appear in intellisense

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oop

I added a new class file to the app_code directory. For some reason though I can't access it through other pages. Any ideas why?

Code:

```
Public Class PDFHelper
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
...
```

The following code produces error "PDFHelper is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Code:

```
Dim formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath)
```

Comment: Try removing the `Shared`, build the project and retry. If it works, then you might be calling it from another project

Comment: @Nadeem_MK That didn't work but thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that there was something weird in the class. I recreated the class (using the same code, which is confusing) and all of a sudden saw compile errors. I addressed those and then I was able to access the class, methods, etc...

Comment: You should have posted what compile errors you addressed to explain the root cause of problem... like whether the broken code you wrote in the file prevented you accessing the class from elsewhere or Visual Studio failed to catch your broken code compile errors etc.

Comment: Thanks @SivaGopal. Actually I think the problem was that the properties of the vb class file was not set to Compile. Once I did that I could refer to the class, properties and methods from other places in code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to import your PDFHelper class, that or use the fully qualified name to access the method:

NameSpace.Class.Method

instead of

Class.Method

Answer (score 0):

I created the class from scratch and all of a sudden it worked. Very weird. Same code.